# Conservation of orbital momentum for the real scalar field (Such as Klein-Gordon Field)

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws

My QFT course is following the book Quantum field theory of Franz Mandl and Graham Shaw. However there are some things unclear to me.

1. They state that if we carry out the following transformation,
   $$ x_{\alpha} \rightarrow x'_{\alpha} \equiv x_{\alpha} +\delta_{\alpha} +\epsilon_{\alpha \beta}x^{\beta}$$
   where $\delta_\alpha$ is an infinitesimal displacement and $\epsilon_{\alpha \beta}$ is an infinitesimal antisymmetric tensor. Then the book states that this transformation will induce a transformation in the fields which we assume to be 
   $$ \phi_{r}(x) \rightarrow \phi'_{r}(x')\equiv \phi_r(x) + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\alpha \beta}S^{\alpha \beta}_{sr}\phi_s(x).$$
   My question is how you can you see that the transformation indeed has to be of the above form?
2. From this transformation rule they then derive conservation of momentum and angular momentum. For angular momentum this is
   $$ M^{\alpha \beta} = \frac{1}{c}\int d^3x \{(x^{\alpha}\mathcal{T}^{0\beta}-x^{\beta}\mathcal{T}^{0\alpha})+c\pi_r(x) S^{\alpha \beta}_{rs}\phi_s(x)\} $$
   where
   $$ \mathcal{T}^{\alpha \beta} = \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \phi_{r,\alpha}}\frac{\partial \phi_r}{\partial x_{\beta}}-\mathcal{L}g^{\alpha \beta}$$
   and here $\mathcal{L}$ was the Lagrangian. The book then states that we know from the conservation of angular momentum of the field (equation above) that a single scalar field possesses orbital, but no spin, angular momentum. Why does this directly follow?

***My attempt at 2:***
Since we only have one field we can rewrite the transformation of the field under a rotation as,
$$ \phi(x) \rightarrow \phi'(x')\equiv \phi(x) + \frac{1}{2} \epsilon_{\alpha \beta}S^{\alpha \beta}\phi(x)\\
= (1+\alpha) \phi(x).$$
This nothing else than a rescaling, but since the field equals the wave function it has to be normalized. Therefore $\alpha$ has to be zero. This is the case if $S^{\alpha \beta}=S^{\beta \alpha}$. This is were I am stuck and I don't have any idea if it is even correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $\alpha$ doing there? And what is $\pi_r$ equal to?

Comment: I used the $\alpha$ to replace the numerical $\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{\alpha\beta}S^{\alpha\beta}$ and the $\pi_r(x)$ is the conjugate of the field, i.e. $\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial(\dot{\phi}_r)}$.

Comment: $S$ is called the spin tensor and is 0 for a scalar field. Scalar means that there's a full invariance of the field under the Poincaré group, in particular over the Lorentz one. There is no wave function anywhere, the fields are classical functions (or distributions if you prefer), so the "scaling argument" is faulty.

Comment: 1. An infinitesimal rotation/LT is most certainly not a rescaling. 
2. $\phi$ is a classical field. It has absolutely nothing to do with a wave function. 3. Rotation/LT generators are not symmetric.

Comment: So for the second part it is really in the word scalar, meaning that is really invariant for the whole Poincarré. Thus for a single real field this will not necessary be the case in general?